# "No such file or directory error" with libcrypto.so.1.0.0 in spite of installing libssl

Tags: libraries

When trying to run a game, I got the error message

```
`/home/relax/.config/itch/apps/white/Whitev2/White: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
```

I googled around, and the most common solution was to install `libssl1.0.0`. I already had it installed, so that didn't solve the problem. I figured out that the problem might have been that `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` was in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`, rather than in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`, like most applications might have expected it to be. I tried creating a symlink, but that also didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Providing a link to the game you are trying to play could be useful..

Comment: https://bedstuck.itch.io/white

I also experience the same error when trying to run Undertale.

Answer (score 0):

White is a 32bit binary that depends on a number of i386 libs. You'll need to install all of them. Running `ldd /path/to/White` will show which ones are missing.

In your case you're likely only missing 1 (maybe you have wine installed which will install quite a number of i386 packages.

So run this & try again,

`sudo apt install libssl1.0.0:i386`

Comment: Oh dang, thanks! That was pretty obvious, in hindsight.